# Matlab: How do you seperate text in existing cell

Tags: matlab

I'm a bit new to the matlab world, and I'm running into an issue that I'm sure has an easy solution.

I've imported some data from a text file and parsed out the headers, which resulted in a 1x35 cell called Data.  In each cell (for example Data{1,1,1}) is data that looks like:

```
'600000   -947.772827   -107.045776    -70.818062'
'600001   -920.431396    -86.098122    -56.485119'
'600002   -878.332886    -88.673630    -85.249130'
'600003   -851.637695    -68.546539    -96.691711'
'600004   -834.707642    -28.951260    -73.218872'
'600005   -783.431580     40.657402     24.242268'
```

The problem is, each line is contained in a single column.  I'd like to parse it out so that I have 4 columns instead of one.

I tried parsing out the Data cell even further using:

```
textscan(Data{1,1,1}, '%u%f10%f10%f10', 1)
```

But it resulted in the following error:

```
Error using textscan
First input must be of type double or string.
```

Can I use textscan this way, or do I need to use some other method to break out the text?

Comment: `textscan` requires a **single** number or string.  Is that input a cell array of strings?  Specifically, is that a `6 x 1` array of cells?

Comment: Yes it is.  And going row by row would be horribly inefficient :-/

Comment: Unfortunately will cell arrays, you don't have a choice!  When it comes to text and data processing with cell arrays, a lot of the things you need to do can only be done if you iterate over each cell.

Comment: I can, however, suggest regular expressions, but I don't know how familiar you are with those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `textscan`, you can only specify a single string or a single number.  With your input, I suspect it is a 6 x 1 cell array of strings. As such, you have no choice but to iterate over each cell and convert each cell array contents with `textscan`  Also, get rid of the `%10` spacing as it's actually screwing up where you're parsing out the string.  Also, set the identifier to identify the first number you see to `double` (`%f`) as opposed to unsigned integer (`%u`) to allow for easier conversion.

Therefore, do something like this:

```
>> Data{1,1,1} = {'600000   -947.772827   -107.045776    -70.818062'
'600001   -920.431396    -86.098122    -56.485119'
'600002   -878.332886    -88.673630    -85.249130'
'600003   -851.637695    -68.546539    -96.691711'
'600004   -834.707642    -28.951260    -73.218872'
'600005   -783.431580     40.657402     24.242268'};

>> format long g;
>> vals = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) cell2mat(textscan(x, '%f%f%f%f', 1)), Data{1,1,1}, 'uni', 0))

vals =



Columns 1 through 3

                    600000               -947.772827               -107.045776
                    600001               -920.431396                -86.098122
                    600002               -878.332886                 -88.67363
                    600003               -851.637695                -68.546539
                    600004               -834.707642                 -28.95126
                    600005                -783.43158                 40.657402

  Column 4

                -70.818062
                -56.485119
                 -85.24913
                -96.691711
                -73.218872
                 24.242268
```

That statement `vals = ...` is quite a mouthful, but easy to explain.  Start with this statement:

```
cell2mat(textscan(x, '%f%f%f%f', 1))
```

For a given cell `x` in `Data{1,1,1}`, we want to parse out four numbers for each string that is stored in `x`.  `textscan` will place these numbers as individual cell elements into a cell array.  We want to convert each element into a numeric array, and so [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) is required for us to do so.

In order to operate over all of the elements in `Data{1,1,1}`, we need to use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to allow us to do so:

```
cellfun(@(x) cell2mat(textscan(x, '%f%f%f%f', 1)), Data{1,1,1}, 'uni', 0)
```

The first input is a function that operates on each cell stored in `Data{1,1,1}` (the second input).  We are basically telling `cellfun` that we want to operate on each cell in the cell array stored in `Data{1,1,1}` in the way I talked about before.  This function has input parameter `x`, which is one cell from `Data{1,1,1}`.  Now, the `uni` flag is set to 0 because the output of `cellfun` will not be a single number, but an **array** of numbers - one array per line that you have in your cell array.  The output of this stage would be a 6 element cell array where each location is a 4 element numeric array.  To finish it off, we call `cell2mat` on this output to finally convert our text into a 2D matrix and therefore:

```
vals = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) cell2mat(textscan(x, '%f%f%f%f', 1)), Data{1,1,1}, 'uni', 0))
```

`format long g` allows for better display formatting so we can see both the dominant number as well as the floating point numbers neatly.

Comment: @PWiggin - Oh you don't mind this answer!  Great, you're welcome!

Comment: It definitely answered the question I posted.  Perhaps a better question would have been "how do I import data without using cells?"  But for now, I'm happy just getting the structure completed.